# Facebook API, single user feed?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I haven't had the chance to work with (any) Facebook APIs, I want to create a simple app that will only list posts from a single (specific) FB user, so I don't want to create login for bunch of users.

I just want to have an app that will list everything that a certain person posts on his FB. Is this possible and can someone point me to the right direction? I'll either do it with Node or Rails. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [koala](https://github.com/arsduo/koala#graph-api), simply get an (your) access token from the Graph API Explorer and start exploring. You shouldn't have any issues returning your feed. Koala handles FB's API pagination for you and everything else.